# Oreo - Autofill Framework background highlight color

Tags: android, android-autofill-manager

Is it possible to change EditText autofill highlight color? By default  it has yellow background that may be incompatible with application design.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Android documentation, to change highlight color you have to edit application theme. You can set color or drawable to `android:autofilledHighlight` parameter.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
    <item name="android:autofilledHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

To apply theme to an application set theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application ...
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```